# Silverlight 3 can run out of the browser.. what extra functionality this offers for developer.. and for the user?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

Silverlight 3 can run out of the browser.. what extra functionality this offers for the developer.. and for the user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it allows the disconnected (no need of internet connection) use of sl application + start menu shortcut + some other things you can read about [here](http://mokosh.co.uk/post/2009/04/21/silverlight-3-out-of-browser-oob-applications/).

Answer (score 3):

It allows the user to have a desktop experience without longlasting installations and with quick and easy removing of applications. The barrier to download, install and try an application is much lower, which is good for both, the developer and the user. The developer has greater chances to distribute it's application and the user won't miss a great app because it has a 500MB setup.exe and an one hour installing process.

Answer (score 0):

It also allows for more isolated storage (25MB vs 1MB on the web).  This will be nice for a lot of applications that were previously starved for space.

Comment: Those numbers are defaults, not limits.  The iso storage can be increased with a call to System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.IncreaseQuotaTo().

Answer (score 0):

More access to the keyboard (e.g. the function keys) when in out-of-browser mode since the browser is not intercepting them.